# std::ostream outputs something wrong

Tags: c++, iostream, virtual-functions

I have created code with some classes, which all are derived from `Object` class and have `virtual` method `repr`, which return `Bytes` object. `Bytes` object is just a layer over `vector<char>`, but is also based from Object and has virtual `repr` function.

All classes (including `Bytes`) has overloaded method `operator bool() const`. I'm trying to use `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& sstream, const Object& object)` to output these objects. But when I try to do it, I always see `1` istead of all objects. I guess that all my objects are converted to `bool` type before sending to function.

It happens only if I use function as part of static library.

If I insert code of this function right before `int main(int argc, char** argv)`, everything goes well. What am I doing wrong?

If it may help, here is the code of the function.

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& sstream,
                         const Object& object)
{
  Bytes repr;
  size_t length;
  vector<char> stack;
  repr = object.repr();
  repr.copy(stack);
  stack.push_back(0);
  sstream << &stack[0];
  return sstream;
}
```

However I'm sure it doesn't depends on code of the function, but can depend on its declaration.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

It seems that error is anywhere else. It seems that code for functions is not included, though I have it in static library (`ar t libmyapp.a` shows it). Code is works only right before `main` function. Is it possible to fix it?

Comment: Something alerts me about relying on the address of `stack` after the function ends and it gets destroyed.

Comment: @chris Just now I've tried to copy elements of vector to allocated with `new` array of char and then "shift" it to stream. It doesn't work too.

Comment: @chris It seems that error is anywhere else. It seems that code for functions is not included, though I have it in static library (`ar t libmyapp.a` shows it). Code is works only right before `main` function.

Comment: I'm curious how Bytes.copy works. Could it be dumping 1s and 0s (integers) into the char vector, which, upon encountering a 0, terminates printing because it is a formatted string op?

Comment: No, it can't. It iterates over elements using `vector.begin()` and `vector.end()` and I've already checked it. I've already found that code works if I place it in file just before main function.